# Return to xbmc from console

Tags: raspbmc, kodi, terminal

I'm using Raspbmc. I can drop to the console by using the 'off' button in the XBMC UI and then pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

However, how do I return to XBMC from the console? Typing `exit` in the console returns me to the XMBC UI. However, once I did this, I cannot return to the console from the UI. Now the intermediate screen that asks me to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't appear anymore and the console reappears immediately. I can work in the console, but after a minute or so, the XBMC UI just takes over.

Is using `exit` to leave the console wrong? What do I need to do to correctly restart XBMC after spending time in the console?

Comment: First of all, I tried to recreate the problem and the latest version never seems to send me to that console hitting escape. That said, I trust you know the password and user (it's in the faq pi:raspberry) and in case you didn't know, hitting ctrl-alt-Fn n=2..? gives you other consoles in case you are only after some console and not that particular one (if yes please tell us why).

Comment: I'm not at home to try , but what about this "sudo initctl start xbmc"

Answer (score 3):

You can start or stop XBMC from the terminal using upstart.

```
$ sudo initctl start xbmc
$ sudo initctl stop xbmc
```

*Sources*

- http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/frequently-asked-questions/

Answer (score 0):

Re:Answer1, I had a similar problem, after doing 
$ sudo initctl start xbmc
I got a message saying it was already running,
I typed
$ startx
...and I got back into Raspxbmc.